# Есть ли альтернатива background-attachment, только не для фона, а для тега img

Tags: html, css

Нужно повторить эффект **background-attachment: fixed;** но не для фона блока, а для тега **img**

Answer (score 0):

Такого эффекта можно добиться так:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="img" src="https://sun9-78.userapi.com/impg/hrpxPVMrMOG8G2efwxjzgR0b53iQrN49EmcBvA/ENN78xsetq0.jpg?size=789x789&quality=96&sign=f5c1471634e14e9d46e1a542ce81e58e&type=album">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручил